# syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)というエラーなのですが、lineで指定された行の周辺の記述を変えても解決しません。

Tags: php

```
<?php
//HTTPヘッダーで文字コードを指定
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
?>
<?php

//h()関数の読み込み
require_once 'h.php';
//checkinput()関数の読み込み
require_once 'checkinput.php';

//POSTされたデータのチェック
$_POST = checkinput($_POST);

//三項演算子で検索文字列の有無を判定し処理
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? trim($_POST['data']) : '';
//入力された検索文字列をexplode()関数で半角スペースで区切って配列に代入
//全角スペースはmb_convert_kana()関数で半角スペースに変換
$datalist = explode('', mb_convert_kana($data, 's'));
//値が空の要素を削除
$datalist = array_filter($datalist,function($val){
    return $val != '';
});
//値でソートしてキーを0から振り直す
sort($datalist);
?>
```

この部分が1行目～27行目のコードになっています。
エラーメッセージにはline 10とあるので、`require_once 'checkinput.php';`
の周辺だと思うのですが周辺をいじっても解決しませんでした。

cehckinput.phpはこのコードの書かれたファイルと同じ階層に存在しています。

ちなみにそれ以降のコードは以下のとおりで、

```
<?php
if(!empty($datalist)){
    //データベース設定の読み込み
    require_once __DIR__ .'database.php';

    try{
        //mysqlデータベースに接続
        $db = new PDO($dsn,$dbUser,$dbPass);
        //プリペアドステートメントのエミュレーションを無効にする
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
        //エラーが発生した場合、例外がスローされるようにする
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //sql文の準備
        //検索文字列の数だけ[:data0][:data1]…のようにプレースホルダを用意
        $where = '';
        foreach ($datalist as $key => $value) {
            $where .= sprintf('AND name LIKE :name%d , $key');
        }
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM goods WHERE 1' . $where;

        $prepare = $db->prepare($sql);

        //sql文のプレースホルダに値をバインドしてクエリを実行
        for($i = 0; $i < count($datalist); $i++){
            //検索文字列の中のワイルドカード文字及びエスケープ文字をエスケープ
            $link = preg_replace('/([_%\\\\])/u', '\\\\$1', $datalist[$i]);
            $prepare->bindValue(':name'.$i, '%' .$link .'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $prepare->execute();
        $result = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($result) == 0){
            print '<p>「'.h($data).'」はデータベースに登録がありません</p>';
        }else{
            print '<p>「'.h($data).'」はデータベースに登録がありました</p>';
?>
            <p>検索結果</p>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>商品名</th>
                <th>価格</th>
            </tr>
<?php
            foreach ($result as $row){
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php h($row['id']) ?></td>
                <td><?php h($row['name']) ?></td>
                <td><?php h($row['prace']) ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php
            }
            print '</table>';
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM goods';
        $prepare = $db->prepare($sql);
        $prepare->execute();
        $result = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
            <p>データベースの内容一覧</p>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>商品名</th>
                <th>価格</th>
            </tr>
<?php
            foreach ($result as $row){
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php h($row['id']) ?></td>
                <td><?php h($row['name']) ?></td>
                <td><?php h($row['prace']) ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php
            }
            print '</table>';

//接続でいない場合、PDOException例外がスローされるのでキャッチする
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print 'エラーが発生しました。。　内容：' . h($e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

こうなっています。

長くなって申し訳ないですが、力を貸していただきたいです。
どこがおかしいでしょうか？

Comment: 「php -l checkinput.php」を実行するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: 全く同じエラーが出ました。
function checkinput($var){
 if(is_array($var)){
  return array_map('h',$var);
 }else{
  return htmlspecialchars('checkinput',$var);
 }else{
  //magic_quotes_gpcへの対策
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
   $var = stripslashes($var);
  }
  //nullバイト攻撃対策
  //nullバイトを含む制御文字が含まれていないかをチェック（最大1000文字）
  if(preg_match('/\A[\r\n\t[:^cntrl:]]{0,1000}\z/u',$var) == 0){
   die('不正な入力です。');
  }
  return $var;
 }
}
以上がコードとなっています。

コメントでは改行されないんですね…
コード見づらくてすみません。

Comment: else 節が2個あることが原因ですね。

Comment: かなり単純なことでお恥ずかしい…
ありがとうございました！

Comment: @まふゆ 解決出来た場合には自身で回答を書き込んで、その回答にチェックを入れていただけると、本質問が解決された事が分かりやすくなります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> else 節が2個あることが原因ですね。

コメント欄でいただいた指摘を回答とさせて頂きます。

Comment: 「ありがとう」のみを「回答」とするのは、このサイトではよくない行為です。（お気持ちはわかります。）そうではなく、コメントをまとめてどのように解決したかを書いてくだされば、次以降の質問で、すぐに回答してくださる方が増えると思います。

Comment: 理解が足りずすみません。
コメントをまとめてどのように解決したかをコメントに書けば良いのでしょうが？回答に書けばよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 自分で経緯をまとめてもいいし、コメントをそのまま引用でも良いです。今の段階では、 Yusuke Ando が まふゆ のかわりに回答を編集してくださっています。ここからの質問者としてのあなたの役目は、この回答にチェックを入れて、この質問には回答があるぞとみんなに伝えることです。（このサイトは、他のユーザの質問や回答を変更する手段が用意されています。あなたが前向きにしていれば、今回のように、他の人が編集するなどして助けてくれるでしょう。）慣れて権限がついたなら、良い回答や、助けてくれた人にプラス投票をしていきましょう。

Comment: 分かりました。
明日にならないとチェックが入れられないようなので、明日チェックを入れさせていただきたいと思います。
tomuteさん、Yusuke Andoさん、Hiroshi Yamamotoさん、ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: @YusukeAndo 他の人が後から読んだ時に分かりやすいように、解決方法と直接関係のない、コメントでのやり取り部分を回答から削除しました。